# unable to create signature using cryto in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, rsa, sha256

I am trying to create a signature using RSA-SHA25 algorithm. This is the code bellow

```
const data = "My data";    
const sign = crypto.createSign("RSA-SHA256");
sign.update(Buffer.from(data, "utf8"));
signature = sign
  .sign({ key: privateKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING })
  .toString("base64");
```

The problem is I am getting this error. I searched through out the internet but unable to find the right solution.

> internal/crypto/sig.js:105
> const ret = this[kHandle].sign(data, format, type, passphrase, rsaPadding,
> ^

> Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the posted NodeJS code the key is passed as an object, so in general the properties `key`, `format` and `type` must be used for the key description, which is explained in detail in the documentation of [`sign.sign(privateKey[, outputEncoding])`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_sign_sign_privatekey_outputencoding) and [`crypto.createPrivateKey(key)`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createprivatekey_key).

Hereby `key` contains the key material, `format` specifies the encoding (`'pem'` or `'der'`, where `'pem'` is the default) and `type` the type (for RSA this can be `'pkcs1'` or `'pkcs8'`, where this parameter is only required if `format` is equal to `'der'`).

If these properties are inconsistent, generally an error will occur.

For example, in the case of the posted code, `format` is not explicitly specified, so the default `'pem'` is used. If the key `privateKey` is a DER encoded key (in a buffer), there is an inconsistency which leads to the error message *Error: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line*: Because of the implicitly specified `format` `'pem'`, a PEM encoded key is expected with the respective header, which is missing for a DER encoded key, resulting in the error. The solution is to explicitly specify `format` and `type`, e.g.:

```nodejs
{ key: privateKey, format: 'der', type: 'pkcs8', padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING }
```

for a PKCS#8 key (or `'pkcs1'` for a PKCS#1 key).

Conversely, for

```nodejs
{ key: privateKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING }
```

`privateKey` must be a PEM encoded key as string or buffer.